# How to bring Excel chart data labels in front of axis

Tags: excel, vba

I created a custom data label series using "Value From Cells" to have a label at the end of the chart displaying the current value.  Unfortunately, the axis labels are "on top"/"in front" of the data label.  Is there any way to change this (VBA or otherwise)?

[image]

Comment: Modify then scale a little. Not sure that it will work but worth a try.

Comment: Instead, would you be open to simply moving the label to the left/right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came up with a kind of absurd workaround. I'll do my best to explain it here in case anyone else comes across this.

To make this easier, the point I want the data label for will be called A. This is the latest value of the original series that should be labeled off to the right of the chart.

1. I removed the old data labels.
2. I created a scatter plot with one point: (0,y). The y value was set to A as a percentage of the minimum to maximum y-axis range. So if A is 3 and the y-axis range is -2 to 10, then the y-value would be 3/(10 - -2) = 3/12 = .25. So the result would be a scatter plot with one point at (0,.25).
3. I made everything on the scatter plot chart (e.g. plot area) invisible EXCEPT the one scatter plot point. This gives me a floating scatter point that moves up and down the y-axis, depending on the percentage calculated above.
4. I added a y-axis to the scatter plot, and set the minimum to 0 and the maximum to 1. I then removed the axis. This was only to set that min/max.
5. I moved my scatter plot so that the top/bottom of the plot area was exactly even with the top/bottom of the plot area of my original chart. So now, I have a single point that is moving up and down along the height of the original chart's plot area. Its up/down position is determined by A, and it will line up exactly with the y-position of A (because that's how I designed it).
6. I added a data label to the scatter plot and hid the scatter plot series. So now, I have my data label in the correct up/down position (lined up with the A).
7. Change the data label "Label Options" --> "Label Contains" to "Value From Cells". Then reference a cell with A's value that we want displayed (instead of the % value we used to get the up/down position right).
8. Last step is just to move the scatter plot left/right until it's in the perfect spot to the right of the plot area, and done!

Then repeat that miserable process for 16 charts with copy/paste when possible. Hope this helps someone else!